# Spring AppContext in Maven

Tags: spring, maven

I am using Maven for creating my project structure. The following is the way I am doing

- Generate Archetype
- Have the following modules - Ear, War and WarSource (I am deleting the src, ejb and jar folders)
- So my EAR will have 2 modules - War and WarSource which inturn have src/main/java and src/main/resource folders

Question is - where should my application context reside so that I avoid the File Not Found error during runtime.

Thanks

Comment: how are you instantiating your appcontext?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using spring mvc it will be in the war src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ directory. Also if you're using spring you may not even need an ear file, you should read up on that to be sure you're not adding unnecessary complexity.